# No response after click button login

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-sign-on, jogetworkflow

I currently create a PHP Login using Joget SSO. The Joget already have its own script of SSO. I follow the steps and if the username and password is matched, it will alert "login sucessfully" else, it will alert "login failed". Below is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     </head>
    <body>

    <h2>Login Form</h2>

    <form >
      <div class="imgcontainer">
        <img src="img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>

        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

        <button type="submit" onclick="loginCallback()">Login</button>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
        <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
      </div>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/jw/js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/jw/js/json/util.js" ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var loginCallback = {
            success : function(response){
                if(response.username != "roleAnonymous"){
                    alert("login successfully");
                }else{
                    alert("login fail");
                }
            }
        };
        AssignmentManager.login('https://workflow.topglove.com:10443/jw/web/json/directory/user/sso', 'admin', 'admin', loginCallback);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: errors in your console? loginCallback is not a function

Answer (score 0):

loginCallback is an object.You can either make it as a function or use loginCallback.success() inide your onclick.

Also I doubt if the control goes inside document.ready method.You can add a console inside and check if it is declaring loginCallback variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the below

function loginCallback() {
                success : function(response){
                    if(response.username != "roleAnonymous"){
                        alert("login successfully");
                    }else{
                        alert("login fail");
                    }
                }
            };
            AssignmentManager.login('https://workflow.topglove.com:10443/jw/web/json/directory/user/sso', 'admin', 'admin', loginCallback());
```